# Pulling the "ID" to the Session when the Button in the Table is Clicked

Tags: php, mysql, session

[image]

When I click on the button, I want to transfer the ID information from the database to SESSION. But I want to do this without revealing ID information in any way. GET-POST exposes data, so I want to use SESSION.

```
<?php 
include "config.php";

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender']; 

    $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `firstname`='$firstname',`lastname`='$lastname',`email`='$email',`password`='$password',`gender`='$gender' WHERE `id`='$user_id'"; 

    $result = $conn->query($sql); 

    if ($result == TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully.";
    }else{
        echo "Error:" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
} 

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $user_id = $_GET['id']; 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$user_id'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql); 

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $first_name = $row['firstname'];
            $lastname = $row['lastname'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            $password  = $row['password'];
            $gender = $row['gender'];
            $id = $row['id'];            
        } 
    ?>
        <h2>User Update Form</h2>

        <form action="" method="post">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Personal information:</legend>
            First name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <br>
            Last name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>">
            <br>
            Email:<br>
            <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
            <br>
            Password:<br>
            <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
            <br>
            Gender:<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" <?php if($gender == 'Male'){ echo "checked";} ?> >Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" <?php if($gender == 'Female'){ echo "checked";} ?>>Female
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Update" name="update">
          </fieldset>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>       

    <?php
    } else{ 
        header('Location: view.php');
    } 
}
?>
```

In short, I want to store the "ID" from the database on the server side.

Comment: If you require more help, please provide a [mre] of the issue as per the [ask] guide. Fixing descriptions alone is often tricky. Code tends to be easier to fix :-). You can [edit] your post - thanks.

Comment: @ADyson 
I added my pictures and codes, I would be happy if you help.

Comment: user_id already comes from the client side, so not sure adding that to the session would help with keeping it private.

Comment: @Shadow 
If I manage to transfer it with SESSION, I will remove that part.

Comment: So, what prevents you from pushing the user_id into the session, when you generate the form and reuse it in this form processing code?

Comment: Warning: Undefined array key "uid" in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\update.php on line 6

Comment: I get this error. I am assigning data to SESSION but it gives an error like this.

Comment: 1) that's not an error, that's a warning. 2 there are detailed canonical questions and answers to this warning already on SO, see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr

Comment: Your code, as shown, doesn't contain any reference to "uid" anywhere. Again please provide code which would actually demonstrate the problem.

Comment: P.S. `But I want to do this without revealing ID information in any way`...why? What difference does that make? Realistically, at some point in the process the browser has to be able to tell the server which row needs to be updated. There's no way around that. If you feel the need for some reason, there might be ways to obfuscate the data somewhat, but ultimately the information has to be transferred from client to server, in some format, for any of this to work. Since the user requested to update a specific record, it's unclear why you feel you need to hide this from the user.

Comment: P.P.S. **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Comment: Also, please don't store passwords in plain text - that is another security risk (because plain-text passwords can be stolen by hackers). Learn about [password hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead. See also [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords). Hashed passwords cannot be decoded by anyone who steals them.

Comment: And please bring your SQL error handling into the 21st century. Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should never be echoing error data deliberately - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident. In a live environment you should always log all PHP errors to a file.

Comment: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong (as above). It is not generally a suitable topic for an inexperienced or beginner programmer. Any [modern development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. I recommend focusing your time on learning PHP and adding genuine value to your application with new features, not something you can re-use a (reliable, well-made) product for.