# Storing ID information in the line with SESSION

Tags: php, session

```
<?php 
include "config.php";
session_start();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>View Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>users</h2>

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
            <?php
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>
                <?php $_SESSION["id"] = $row['id'];?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="update.php">Edit</a>&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>                       
                <?php
                }
            }
            ?>                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I want to print the ID information on the line to SESSION. But it always gives me the ID information of the last row. I don't want to use GET/POST, how can I handle it with SESSION?

In short, when you press the EDIT button in the table, the relevant ID will be transferred to the session.

Comment: You have a misunderstanding about the concept of session, please read:
 [What is the difference between Sessions and Cookies in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339783/what-is-the-difference-between-sessions-and-cookies-in-php). A session cannot know which button you've clicked on the client side.

Comment: @shingo  So how can I secretly transfer ID information to another page?

Comment: You can 't. Wether with GET nor with POST requests. There will always be some information about the identifier in the request body. You can disguise your identifier with some .htaccess mod_rewrite magic or use UUID as identifier for your entities. UUID is harder to predict. But ... it will be still a parameter in your GET request or in your POST request.

Comment: @technical You can't, and this concern is unnecessary, because one doctrine of writing server code is never to trust the data sent by the client, verify it before use.

Comment: You asked the same thing [days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77611931/pulling-the-id-to-the-session-when-the-button-in-the-table-is-clicked) and I [already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77611931/pulling-the-id-to-the-session-when-the-button-in-the-table-is-clicked#comment136826818_77611931) exactly what you've just been told now. Why ask again? If you needed clarification, you could have replied to that comment last week